# File not uploading to Google Drive using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, .net-5, closedxml

I'm struggling with an issue where my excel file does not want to upload to Google Drive. I am using this package in another hangfire Task, and those files upload successfully. I am building up an excel file using ClosedXml. I have also tested this code with an existing excel file that I manually created and it still doesn't upload.

Please see my code below:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Generate_Excel_File(customerReports, stream);
    await Save_And_Upload(stream, reportName, startDate, endDate, filePath);
}

private static void Generate_Excel_File(List<QuarterlyDirectCustomerReport> customerReports, MemoryStream stream)
{
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Direct Customers");

        var billTimes = customerReports
                        .Select(x => x.BillTime)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();

        Generate_Header_Titles(worksheet, billTimes);
        Generate_Details(worksheet, customerReports, billTimes, out int lastRowIndex, out decimal[] totalAverageVariances);
        Generate_Totals(worksheet, customerReports, billTimes, lastRowIndex, totalAverageVariances);
        Adjust_Column_Width(worksheet);
        Set_Column_Format(worksheet);

        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
    }
}

private async Task Save_And_Upload(MemoryStream stream, string reportName, string start, string end, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        //stream.Position = 0;

        //using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        //{
        //  stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        //}

        using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            //fileStream.Position = 0;
            await Upload_To_Google_Drive(fileStream, reportName, start, end);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = ex.Message;
    }
}

private async Task Upload_To_Google_Drive(Stream stream, string fileName, string startDate, string endDate)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Uploading {fileName} to Google Drive");
        var service = Get_Service();

        var folderName = $"Bizvoip : {startDate} to {endDate}";
        var folderId = Get_Folder_Id_For(folderName, service);

        var mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";
        var driveFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
        {
            Name = fileName,
            MimeType = mimeType,
            Parents = new string[] { folderId }
        };

        var request = service.Files.Create(driveFile, stream, mimeType);
        request.Fields = "*";

        var results = await request.UploadAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed to upload to Google Drive: " + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

private DriveService Get_Service()
{
    var tokenResponse = new TokenResponse
    {
        AccessToken = _googleDriveOptions.AccessToken,
        RefreshToken = _googleDriveOptions.RefreshToken
    };

    var applicationName = _googleDriveOptions.ApplicationName;
    var username = _googleDriveOptions.Username;

    var apiCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = _googleDriveOptions.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = _googleDriveOptions.ClientSecret
        },
        Scopes = new[] { Scope.Drive },
        DataStore = new FileDataStore(applicationName)
    });

    var credential = new UserCredential(apiCodeFlow, username, tokenResponse);

    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = applicationName
    });

    return service;
}
```

When requesting to upload, I am presented with the following error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Bad Request [400]
Errors [
    Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]
```

The configuration is set up exactly the same as in the task where the files are uploading succesfully.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First thought is to remove **Parents = new string[] { folderId }**  see if it uploads then.   Second thought is please add your authorization code how are you creating service   **var service = Get_Service();**

Comment: Does this only happen with Excel files?

Comment: @mxmissile yup. I haven't tried with other file formats yet as the need is only for excel files.

Comment: Probably should try other types, basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after adding the following function :

```
private static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    string mimeType = "application/unknown";
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();

    var regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
    {
        mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    }

    return mimeType;
}
```

It turned out that the mime type set was not correct. The mimeType I set was "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet". The mimeType returned from the function was "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". Changed the original mimeType and the file uploaded successfully.